# Por que me imprime medio div? vuejs html js css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

No se por que me imprime medio div si para imprimirlo uso el mismo metodo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo html:

```
 <div class= "blocks">
                <div id="show_current_products" v-if = "showcurrentProduct == true">
                    <label v-for="row in actuallist">Actual product's name: {{row.name}}</label>
                    <label v-for="row in actuallist">Actual product's lot: {{row.lot}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

aqui esta otra parte en la que uso el mismo metodo para imprimir pero no me da error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo html:

```
<div class = "blocks">
                <div id="show_previous_products" v-if = "showpreviousProduct == false">
                    <h1>Previous product:</h1>
                    <label v-for="row in list" >Previous product's name: {{row.name}}</label>
                    <label v-for="row in list" >Previous product's lot: {{row.lot}}</label>
                    <label v-for="row in list" >Previous product's quantity packed: {{row.quantity_packed}}</label>
                    <label v-for="row in list" >Previous product's quantity of pallets: {{row.pallet}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

como podran ver en ambos casos uso v-for para los label, pero en el primero siempre me imprime medio div, no imprime medio div si uso table, es decir:

```
 <div class= "blocks">
                <div id="show_current_products" v-if = "showcurrentProduct == true">
                    <table id="list" v-for="row in actuallist">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>Actual product's name: {{row.name}}</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>Actual product's lot: {{row.lot}}</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>    
                        <tr>    
                            <td>
                                <label>Quantity to package: {{row.quantity_to_package}}</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>    
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>Quantity of pallets: {{row.pallets}}</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>Quantity of finished pallets: {{row.finished_pallets}}</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

por que pasa esto??? me esta volviendo loco :(

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que el problema no es el `height` del div padre?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba integrando un `min-height: $medida-minima;` para asegurarte que cuando se tenga el tamaño mínimo y pueda mostrarlo de manera adecuada, por otra parte si pudieras agregar una parte de tu CSS seria de mucha ayuda. Saludos.

```css
.blocks{
   background-color: #2b880e;
   width: 50%;
   min-height: 120px;
   padding: 10px;
   margin:10px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class = "blocks">
  <div id="show_previous_products_1">
      <h1>Previous product:</h1>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's name: </p>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's lot: </p>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's quantity packed: </p>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's quantity of pallets: </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
  <div id="show_previous_products_2">
      <h1>Previous product:</h1>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's name: </p>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's lot: </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
  <div id="show_previous_products_2">
      <h1>Previous product:</h1>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's name: </p>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's lot: </p>
      <p v-for="row in list" >Previous product's quantity packed: </p>
  </div>
</div>
```